# Create Calendar Events in Google Sheets triggered by Date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want my Google Spreadsheet to automatically create a calendar event triggered by a date.

This is my Spreadsheet:

[Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Pqhq5wgLR5NLz_fhvOtKnu3dQ0cMK_j_vKbR736to4/edit?usp=sharing)

This is my sheet "H&S Reviews":

[image]

- Cell K1 = TODAY()
- Column K3:K is the startDate of the event Column
- G3:G is the endDate of the event Column
- C3:C is the enventName
- Column D3:D is the Description of the event

I want to automatically create a calendar event when a date in column K equals the date in K1.

I have created the following calendarEvent Google Apps Script:

```js
//Send Calendar Invites for H&S Reviews
function createCalendarEvent() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("H&S Reviews").activate();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 3;i<=lastRow;i++){

    var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i, 9).getValue();
    var todaysDate = sheet.getRange(1, 11).getValue();
    var startDate = sheet.getRange(i, 11).getValue();
    var endDate = sheet.getRange(i, 7).getValue();  
    var eventName = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
    var description = sheet.getRange(i, 4).getValue();
        
 if (todaysDate == startDate){
 var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById({embed?src=tga.assist%40uzabus.co.nz&ctz=Pacific%2FAuckland});
 var event =  calendar.createEvent(eventName, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate)).setDescription(description);
Logger.log('Event ID: ' + event.getId());
    }
  }
}
```

The script doesnt create an event. I am also not sure if I have the setDescription coding correct. Would really appreciate help with this please.

Comment: If `emailAddress` of `var emailAddress = sheet.getRange(i, 18).getValue()` is not the valid calendar ID for `CalendarApp.getCalendarById()`, such error occurs. So how about confirming the value again?

Comment: Thank you - that was silly of me. I ran the script with no errors this time but it hasn't created an event. Do you see anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your updated script, `todaysDate` and `startDate` are retrieved from the cell "K1". When the value of cell "K1" is the date object, the date objects are compared. By this, the result is always `false`. So how about modifying `if (todaysDate == startDate){` to `if (todaysDate.getTime() == startDate.getTime()){`? Or how about modifying `sheet.getRange(1, 11).getValue()` to `sheet.getRange(1, 11).getDisplayValue()`? But I'm not sure about your actual situation. So if this was not the direct solution, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you - your first suggestion errored "Event start time must be before event end time" but the dates in column K are all 14 days before column G. Your second suggestion did not error but did not create a calendar event

Comment: @McChief Can you inspect (either through debug or Logger) the start & end times you're passing?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize my proposal didn't resolve your issue. This is due to my poor skill. I still need to study more. In order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: @Tanaike - Thank you for helping - spreadsheet added to the question

Comment: Thank you for providing the Spreadsheet. In your Spreadsheet, the cell "K1" is `=TODAY()`. And when the cells of "K3:K23" are seen, the value retrieved by `=TODAY()` is not included in the cells of "K3:K23". By this, the if statement is always `false`. If you want to test the script in the if statement, how about copying the value of cell "K3" to "K1" instead of `=TODAY()`?

Comment: Thanks - that didn't error but didn't create an event either

Comment: Can you update your shared Spreadsheet for replicating your current issue in your replying?

Comment: @Tanaike I have added a button to the top of the sheet

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. It will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that I think are tripping you up:

```
CalendarApp.getCalendarById(emailAddress)
```

This should be reading the calendar ID that you're wanting to modify, and not the email address string.  Are you meaning to do getCaledarsByName(emailAddress) in that you have the calendars stored with the email address of the person as their name?  If that's the case then I'll need to modify this answer a bit since getting the calendars by Name returns an array.

From the example it looks like you're wanting to create a calendar events in one calendar only.  If that is the case, the calendar ID could be hard coded -- you can get the calendar ID by opening it in Google Calendars, clicking on the dots next to the calendar and then the 'ID' is everything after the /calendar/ part of the URL.

```
var calendarDescription = CalendarApp.setDescription(description);
```

This should really be after you create the event since you're not wanting to modify the description of the CALENDAR or the Description of your calendars as a whole, but you are wanting to modify the description of the EVENT.  This part of the code should be:

```
if (todaysDate == startDate){
var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById({{ID OF THE CALENDAR}});
var event =  calendar.createEvent(eventName, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate));
event.setDescription(description);
```

I've also included the call to create the calendar variable and call to the CalendarApp after the comparison of the date strings so that it doesn't do this unnecessarily.  You don't need to assign an event description variable since the return of the .setDescription is the calendar event itself and doesn't require anything done with the return. If you wanted to shorten this even more you can even chain them:

```
var event = calendar.createEvent(eventName, new Date(startDate), new Date(endDate)).setDescription(description);
```

Next, the event that you're going to be creating has a start date that is multiple days before the end date.  You might want to consider what the intent is here.

If you are wanting to create a short event to remind you to do something at a certain time of the day then you really ought to make sure that you simply add a start time and then create a new date variable that adds a certain amount of time to the start time to assign the 'endDate' to the event.  For example, the 'Send Date' in the first row of your example sheet is '26/11/2019' and the 'Review' Date is '10/12/2019', which correspond to your 'startDate' and 'endDate' variables respectively.

Based on what the task name is, would creating an all day event possibly be better for your needs:

```
var event = calendar.createAllDayEvent(title, date);
```

Lastly, some words of caution from having worked a lot with dates.  Be very careful of the format when you are comparing dates to make sure everything is in the same format and time zone. If you continue to test if one is == to the other, then if you miss a day in running the script then you could miss adding events as a consequence.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: I hit post and I noticed a couple places where I believe 1 was accidentally used in place of the variable 'i' when referencing the ranges in the cells in your script. i.e:

```
var description = sheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue();
```

Should be:

```
var description = sheet.getRange(i,4).getValue();
```

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. Each event in the "H&S Review" sheet will be assigned to a different person. I have created emails triggered by the date in column K giving 14 days notice of the expiry in column G. I want to create a calendar event for each person responsible for the review and yes that could be a one-day event 7 days before the event is due. I have added my calendar URL and updated the code as you have suggested (I think). I have changed the code in my question and in the Apps Script of my link. At the moment it errors at line 17. Would really appreciate help with the code

Comment: The ID of the calendar is a alphanumeric string in the URL bar of your browser when you go to the following:

Go to calendar.google.com - > Click on the calendar in question -> Calendar Settings.  

The 'ID' for the calendar is the in the URL bar of your browser and looks like this https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/settings/calendar/cm4iRG9rbGRib21bc2VsbGyLaNvbP

Comment: In the above comment it's the last part (**cm4iRG9rbGRib21bc2VsbGyLaNvbP**) that is the calendar ID.  

Creating a separate calendar event for each person might lead to a lot of different events -- there is a feature in the google calendars to invite guests to an event which could actually take the place of manually or automatically sending a separate email out simply by chaining the following onto the calendar event:  

`event.addGuest({email})` -- this will automatically send them a calendar invite to the calendar event.  You can then have everyone on the same calendar event too.